# Using cache for Database handling in Azure App Service

Tags: php, sql, azure, caching, slim

I'm using Azure's App Service Plan running on Linux and Php 7+. I'm using Slim Framework to create REST API.

In the server, I do various kinds of job but most are related to calling Azure Database for MySQL Server.
My question is:

1. How can I use cache to fasten the retrieval process from MySQL Server? Should I use a Virtual Machine in between my App Service and MySQL Server? Or what can be the best practise? Can I use memcache with Slim Framework?
2. Most of the calls will require an API key to interact. My API keys are stored in the database. What could be the best way to check if the API keys are valid or not. Could storing the keys in the cache will make it work faster and is that a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

the ideal would be:

request -> api management (API Gateway) -> app service -> redis cache / my sql

[image]

The recommended cache solution is Azure Redis Cache.

Your api keys would be generated by API Management where you can track requests per key / rotate and revoke keys.

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cache-aside